# Outputting two different gsub results to two columns with AWK

Tags: bash, awk, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format

I'm  trying to optimize an awk code to generate a new columns into my VCF file.
This is the input (minimal working example):

```
#CHROM  POS GENE    REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  1   2   3   4   5   6
chr14   33925904    EGLN3   A   T   .   .   CSQ=T|  GT:AQ:DP:AD:AB:GQ:PL    0/1:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   1/1:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.
chr14   33925905    EGLN3   G   C   .   .   CSQ=C|  GT:AQ:DP:AD:AB:GQ:PL    ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   0/0:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   1/0:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.
chr14   33925907    EGLN3   G   A   .   .   CSQ=A|  GT:AQ:DP:AD:AB:GQ:PL    ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   0/0:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.
chr14   33925918    EGLN3   T   G   .   .   CSQ=G|  GT:AQ:DP:AD:AB:GQ:PL    ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   1/0:.:0:.:0,0:.:.
chr14   33927014    EGLN3   A   G   .   .   CSQ=G|  GT:AQ:DP:AD:AB:GQ:PL    ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   1/0:.:0:.:0,0:.:.
chr14   33927025    EGLN3   AT  A   .   .   CSQ=-|  GT:AQ:DP:AD:AB:GQ:PL    ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.
chr14   33929079    EGLN3   G   A   .   .   CSQ=A|  GT:AQ:DP:AD:AB:GQ:PL    ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   ./.:.:0:.:0,0:.:.   0/0:.:0:.:0,0:.:.
```

I use this code:

```
paste <(bcftools view $MYVCF | awk -F"\t" 'BEGIN {print "#CHROM\tPOS\tID\tREF\tALT\tQUAL\tFILTER\tINFO"} !/^#/ {print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8}') \ #prints first columns from vcf - Important if file has a vcf header
  <(bcftools query -f '[\t%SAMPLE=%GT]\n' "$MYVCF" |\
    awk 'BEGIN {print "nHet"} {print gsub(/0\|1|1\|0|0\/1|1\/0/, "")}') \ #counts samples (1-6) that have 0/1 or 1/0
    \
  <(bcftools query -f '[\t%SAMPLE=%GT]\n' "$MYVCF" |\
    awk 'BEGIN {print "nHomAlt"} {print gsub(/1\|1|1\/1/, "")}') \
    \ #counts samples with 1/1
  <(bcftools query -f '[\t%SAMPLE=%GT]\n' "$MYVCF" |\
    awk 'BEGIN {print "nHomRef"} {print gsub(/0\|0|0\/0/, "")}')   >> example3.txt

  Which does the following:
```

First, it prints the columns CHR POS ID REF ALT and INFO, then searches for GT values in samples (1-6) with specific 0/0 and prints the counts of samples which have this specific GT in a new column named nHomRef. Does the same to 1/0 (and combinations) and output to column named nHet and then finally does the same to 1/1 combinations and outputs to a new column named hHomRef

This is outputting:

```
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO    nHet    nHomAlt nHomRef
chr14   33925904        EGLN3   A       T       .       .       CSQ=T|  1       1       0
chr14   33925905        EGLN3   G       C       .       .       CSQ=C|  1       0       1
chr14   33925907        EGLN3   G       A       .       .       CSQ=A|  0       0       1
chr14   33925918        EGLN3   T       G       .       .       CSQ=G|  1       0       0
chr14   33927014        EGLN3   A       G       .       .       CSQ=G|  1       0       0
chr14   33927025        EGLN3   AT      A       .       .       CSQ=-|  0       0       0
chr14   33929079        EGLN3   G       A       .       .       CSQ=A|  0       0       1
```

I'm trying to optimize the code so not many subprocesses are created.
To simplify I used only two columns

```
paste <(bcftools view "$MYVCF" | awk -F"\t" 'BEGIN {print "#CHROM\tPOS\tID\tREF\tALT\tQUAL\tFILTER\tINFO"} !/^#/ {print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5}') <(bcftools query -f '[\t%SAMPLE=%GT]\n' "$MYVCF" | awk 'BEGIN {print "nHomAlt\tnHet"} {print gsub(/1\|1|1\/1/, "")} {print gsub(/0\|1|1\|0|0\/1|1\/0/, "")}') >> example3_test.txt
```

How can I output the gsub, inside awk, to the correct column?
So, this snippet

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "nHomAlt\tnHet"} {print gsub(/1\|1|1\/1/, "")} {print gsub(/0\|1|1\|0|0\/1|1\/0/, "")}'
```

To output the correct columns?
I`m getting:

```
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    nHomAlt nHet
chr14   33925904    EGLN3   A   T   .   .   CSQ=T|  1
chr14   33925905    EGLN3   G   C   .   .   CSQ=C|  1
chr14   33925907    EGLN3   G   A   .   .   CSQ=A|  0
chr14   33925918    EGLN3   T   G   .   .   CSQ=G|  1
chr14   33927014    EGLN3   A   G   .   .   CSQ=G|  0
chr14   33927025    EGLN3   AT  A   .   .   CSQ=-|  0
chr14   33929079    EGLN3   G   A   .   .   CSQ=A|  0
    1
    0
    1
    0
    0
    0
    0
```

PS:
Using

```
paste <(bcftools view $MYVCF | awk -F"\t" 'BEGIN {print "#CHROM\tPOS\tID\tREF\tALT\tQUAL\tFILTER\tINFO"} !/^#/ {print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8}')  <(bcftools query -f '[\t%SAMPLE=%GT]\n' "$MYVCF" | awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"; print "nHomAlt\tnHet"} {
 nHet=gsub(/0\|1|1\|0|0\/1|1\/0/, "");
 nHomAlt=gsub(/1\|1|1\/1/, "");
 print nHomAlt,nHet;
}')
```

Seems to give the correct output!

Comment: The `paste/bcftools` is obscuring your problem. The last line of code is all we need, (preferably formatted on multiple lines for easier reading) and a small set of sample input (You have included your required output (good show!) ). Also include your current output and the exact text of any error messages generated. Input, code, ouput, required output/errmessages make for a question where you may not have to explain how you're doing it (-;! . Good luck.

Comment: Note the result of `echo "gsubresult1|1|1/1    gsubresult4" | awk '{print gsub(/1\|1|1\/1/, "", $1)} '` is `2`. It found 2 matches. `gsub()` only modifies the supplied string/fieldNum/variableValue and returns the number of substitutions. You need to the print out the field or variable, so `awk '{gsub(...., $0); print $0}'` will get you moving in the right direction. Good luck.

Comment: Show us your input file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, any time your goal includes "to optimize", your first effort should be to eliminate repeating any work... such as the repeats of

```
bcftools query -f '[\t%SAMPLE=%GT]\n' "$MYVCF" | awk
```

Part of your problem is trying to push your data through `paste` when you already *have* it in `awk`. I think what you really need to do is remember that `print` is going to append an output record separator, or ORS, which by default is a newline character. You could use `printf` to output each field, but I think it's easier to just pass your fields as arguments. You can also set the OFS (output field separator) to delimit them with a tab by default.

Working from your input example, which I stored in a file, you probably just need to manage your data collection and formatting. Here's one possible example:

```
$: awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"; print "nHomAlt\tnHet"} {
 nHet=gsub(/0\|1|1\|0|0\/1|1\/0/, "");
 nHomAlt=gsub(/1\|1|1\/1/, "");
 print nHomAlt,nHet;
}' input
nHomAlt nHet
1       3
0       3
3       2
0       1
0       3
0       0
0       7
0       0
```

You said you wanted counts, and that's what `gsub` returns, so I assume that's why you used it.

What you want probably looks something like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS="\t"; print "#CHROM\tPOS\tID\tREF\tALT\tQUAL\tFILTER\tINFO\tnHet\tnHomAlt\tnHomRef" } {
 nHet=gsub(/0[|/]1|1[|/]0/, "");
 nHomAlt=gsub(/1[|/]1/, "");
 nHomRef=gsub(/0[|/]0/, "");
 print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,nHet,nHomAlt,nHomRef;
}' input # maybe input should be < <( <(bcftools query -f '[\t%SAMPLE=%GT]\n' "$MYVCF" )
```

...which shouldn't need the `paste` *or* the repeated calls to `awk`.

You obviously already know how to substitute your command in for the input. Hopefully that will get you close enough.

Comment: The bcftools view eliminates the header (which is important for processing the vcf itself), but the bcftools query produces a specific output (1=1/0 2=1/1 etc) which is a simplification of the full value of each row on columns 1-6 (to simplify counting the values without errors). I'm thinking of a way to process like you describe, but probably will still need both bcftools calls to process the file correctly!

Comment: Let us see what you come up with. We'll get you there. ;)

Comment: Btw, can I use the same tactic, like nHomAlt=gsub(/1[|/]1/, ""); for a more complex for loop result? like nHomAlt={for (...) {if i=1 {printf header[i]","}; if i=2 {printf /n}}

Comment: What is the goal? Would it make sense? I'm not sure what would be returned there, and would recommend something a bit more explicit.

Comment: I`m not sure if I should start another question because it seems like it is close to answring. The code is: (bcftools view MyVariants.Norm.vcf | awk -F"\t" '/^#CHROM/ {split($0, header, "\t"); print "HomSamplesAlt"} \
    !/^#CHROM/ {for (i=10; i<=NF; i++) {if (gsub(/1\|1|1\/1/, "", $(i))==1) {printf header[i]","}; if (i==NF) {printf "\n"}}}') , which is getting the header value where I have 1/1 in rows and printing it to a column! But as above, I need to print to another columns the sample names of 0/1 or 1/0 and finally the sample names for 0/0.